# JSP Parameter Passing Issue

Tags: html, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

My page flow is like,

```
Jsp1 -> Jsp2 -> ... -> Servlet -> JspN -> ...
```

where, Jsp1 is log in page where user has to give password and username. Now, I want to use username and password value in servlet page. Is it possible to get those value in servlet without passing parameters from Jsp1 to Jsp2 .... to Servlet?

Comment: What are those arrows? HTTP requests? Forwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set them in session in `Jsp2` stage. Get the parameters from request and set them in session as so:

```
<%
    session.setAttribute("username", request.getParameter("username"));
    session.setAttribute("password", request.getParameter("password"));
%>
```

To be able to do this, your `Jsp1` should have fields defined with the same names as the request parameters.

```
<input type="text" name="username"/>
<input type="password" name="password"/>
```

Then in the `Servlet`, you can simply read them as so:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    String username = session.getAttribute("username");
    String password = session.getAttribute("password");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup that's a good approach, ideally though I dont see any reason why you cant use a servlet between jsp 1 and jsp 2.? That way you can retain the values in the request and then use them in  your second jsp.